How to deduce surjective map in constructing semi-free resolution of a module $M$ over a dga $R$？
Let $k$ be a field, $R$ is a differential graded algebra with differential $+1$ degree.  In the book rational homotopy theory,chapter 6. proposition 6.6. author prove that:
(i)Every $(R,d)$-module $(Q,d)$ has a semifree resolution $m:(M,d)\stackrel{\simeq}{\rightarrow}(Q,d).$
Proof: $(i)$ Let $V(0)$ be a free graded $k$-module whose basis is a system of generators of the $k$-module of cocycles of $Q$ . Set $M(0)=(R,d)\otimes(V(0),0).$ The inclusion $V(0)\to Q$ defines a morphism $g(0):(M(0),d)\to(Q,d).$ Clearly $H(g(0))$ is surjective. We now construct an increasing sequence of morphisms $g( k) : ( M( k) , d) \quad \to \quad ( Q, d) .\quad $If$\quad g( k- 1) $ is defned, let $V(k)$ be the free $k$- module whose basis $v_\mathrm{a}$ in degree $i$ is in one to one correspondence with cocycles $w_\mathrm{a}$ representing a system of generators of $\ker H_{i- 1}( g( k- 1) ) .\quad $Set$\quad M( k) \quad = $ $M(k-1)\oplus(R\otimes V(k))$, and put $dv_a=w_a.$ Denote $g(k-1)$ simply by $g.$ Since $g(w_\alpha)$ is a coboundary, $g(w_\alpha)=d(x_\alpha)$ we put $g(k)(v_\alpha)=x_\alpha.$ Finally, set $M=\bigcup_{k}M(k).$
However, I don't undertand  how to deduce the first surjective $g(0)$. When $R$ is dga with zero homology(e.g. $k[x],\partial(x)=1$),and $H(M)\neq 0$. Or when $H^{\leq 0}(R)=0$, from formula $0=H(R)\otimes H(V(0))\cong H(R \otimes V(0))$ leads to no degree 0 surjective map? What goes wrong here?
